# finding the last matching record of a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a function that I want to write and cannot work out how it will work. The first line returns my steps in the order that they should be, and the second line I want to return the last matching step in all the steps for the course. I think I am close but need to know what I've done wrong.

```
course_steps_in_order = course.steps.sort_by(&:component_and_step_order)    
last_completed_step = current_user.completed_steps.where("steps.id in ?", course_steps_in_order).last
```

I am getting the error...

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: ... WHERE "user_steps"."user_id" = 3 AND (step.id in 1,2,4,8,5,...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  "steps".* FROM "steps" INNER JOIN "user_steps" ON "steps"."id" = "user_steps"."step_id" WHERE "user_steps"."user_id" = 3 AND (step.id in 1,2,4,8,5,3,7,6,9) ORDER BY "steps"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

A course has many components which has many steps, as per the below models...

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :components, :dependent => :destroy, :order => "component_order"
  has_many :steps, :through => :components, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :steps, :dependent => :destroy, :order => "step_order"
end

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :component

  def component_and_step_order
    component_order * 100 + step_order
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the collection-enclosing parenthesis:

```
...
last_completed_step = current_user.completed_steps.where("steps.id in (?)", course_steps_in_order).last
```

Now the query will generate correctly like so:

```
... AND (step.id in (1,2,4,8,5))
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems: one you know about and one you don't. The first and most obvious problem is your SQL syntax error that [clyfe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474250/479863) has solved for you. The second problem is that `IN` does not guarantee any particular order so this:

```
current_user.completed_steps.where("steps.id in (?)", course_steps_in_order).last
```

is not guaranteed to give you the last step whose `id` is in `course_steps_in_order` and is not even guaranteed to produce the same result from one execution to the next. If you want to get results out of SQL in a specific order you **must** explicitly specify that order with an ORDER BY clause. For example, I just did this in one of my PostgreSQL tables:

```
=> select id from some_table where id in (1,2,3,4,5);
 id 
----
  1
  5
  2
  3
  4
```

Your approach would give you `4` as the last one when you would be expecting `5`.

Allow me to repeat myself: relational databases are set based and inherently unordered, if you need anything in a particular order then you **must** unambiguously specify that order in an ORDER BY clause.

If you want your `last` call to mean anything useful then you need to convert your `component_and_step_order` method to a `.order` call and include that in your `current_user.completed_steps.where` query.

Comment: I order them in the models via the :order => "step/component_order" calls in the models. This is the ordering that I want, not the id's. Will this fix the issue you are talking about?

Comment: @bouser1188763: Does `current_user.completed_steps` include an `order` call anywhere? If it doesn't then you have a problem. It doesn't matter what you do in the models, you're assuming that `in (2,1,3)` will return rows in the 2-1-3 order but that assumption is invalid.

Comment: yes i see now, it does order them according to when they were created, so as they are forced to progress through the steps in order, this will work (i think). A User has_many :user_steps, :dependent => :destroy do
    def for_course(course)
      joins(:step=> {:component => :course}).where("courses.id = ?", course).order("created_at")
    end
  end
  And then a User also -> has_many :completed_steps, :through => :user_steps, :source => :step

Comment: Is there is an explicit ORDER BY clause in the SQL that gets generated? I don't see where `for_course` would get called by `current_user.completed_steps`. Ordering by `created_at` should give you the order you're after if you use the right `created_at` (but `created_at desc` and `.limit(1)` or `.first` would probably be more efficient).